# box2d boost velocity after collision

Tags: java, box2d, game-engine, game-physics

I'm creating a mobile game powered by andengine and the box2d physics extension

I wanted to know if there is a way to **increase** the velocity of a body
after collision.

thanks,
socksocket

Comment: You could adjust the velocities in the EndContact function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the coefficient of restitution.